# Modelderivative returns DNS lookup timed out error when polling for properties

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

We sometimes experience the following error when uploading a (big) model:

> 11:03:41 0|server  | https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bmVhbmV4LWJ1Y2tldC95OFh5dk5MdS5aeDkuNU1ZMXdwaFJPYjdQNGxlY2g2TC5ud2Q/metadata/8ae18b4e-f201-4971-88e0-9c2e34ce5bb6/properties?forceget=true 202
>   11:03:41 0|server  | { result: 'success' }
>   11:07:38 0|server  | { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN developer.api.autodesk.com developer.api.autodesk.com:443
>   11:07:38 0|server  |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
>   11:07:38 0|server  |   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
>   11:07:38 0|server  |   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
>   11:07:38 0|server  |   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
>   11:07:38 0|server  |   hostname: 'developer.api.autodesk.com',
>   11:07:38 0|server  |   host: 'developer.api.autodesk.com',
>   11:07:38 0|server  |   port: 443,

Do you guys have an idea what the reason could be?

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

can you specify for the beginning file size and format of original file?

Comment: Hi @K_2,
- The original file format is .nwd
- The original file size is 16747087

Maybe some more info:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GqomEGGrZwNYIiVMeSElhGl5-NeACOE3

Comment: @ThomasVanDriessche, would you mind sharing the model with me so I can run some tests here. Send me a link to my email address cyrille at autodesk.com